# httpd - SSLCertificateFile: file '/var/certs/domain.cert' does not exist

Tags: apache-http-server, fedora, ssl, path, httpd

maybe i just can't search in internet but i stuck with that:

I have Fedora Server 31 with `httpd` installed.
I added small `vhosts` config:

```
Listen 3000
<VirtualHost *:3000>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/example.com/public_html"
    ServerName gamebox-x.com
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile "/var/certs/domain.cert"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/var/certs/domain.key"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "/var/certs/ca.cert"
</VirtualHost>
```

On `systemctl status httpd.service`:

```
httpd[21703]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 6 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/example.com.conf:
httpd[21703]: SSLCertificateFile: file '/var/certs/domain.cert' does not exist or is empty
systemd[1]: httpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: httpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

but in file system i actually have all files:

```
ls -l /var/certs
total 24
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 3243 mar 28 18:23 account.key
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1648 mar 29 15:01 ca.cert
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 2277 mar 29 15:01 domain.cert
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 3243 mar 29 15:02 domain.key
```

from my user this files are visible...

What did I miss?

Comment: Do you have SELinux in enforcing mode?

Comment: @garethTheRed , yes it's in enforcing mode... (`SELINUX=enforcing  SELINUXTYPE=targeted`)

Comment: Have you tried temporarily putting it into permissive mode so that you can figure out if it's an SELinux issue or not?

Comment: @garethTheRed , in this mode httpd can't even start...
`httpd.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.`
I actually trying to configure it with `sslh` (i hoped that would be working with nginx)

Comment: I would leave SELinux in permissive mode and investigate this timeout.

Comment: Ok, I figure it out... `chcon -t cert_t file` helps me... But my [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1536740/configuring-sslh-to-work-with-nginx-on-https-port) problem doesn't solved... Even on apache...

Comment: You can answer your own question.  I've not used `sslh` so can't help you there.

Answer (score 2):

To solve my problem i used command:

```
chcon -t cert_t
```

for each file which is related in config...